# Rails: get event name with sneakers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code:

```
require 'json'

class PaymentEvents < Workers
  include Sneakers::Worker

  from_queue "my-queue",
    exchange: 'payment',
    exchange_type: :topic,
    exchange_options: { durable: true },
    queue_options: { durable: true },
    routing_key: 'event.payment.*',
    timeout_job_after: 120

  def internal_work(msg)
    #do stuff here, according to the type of the event

    ack!
  end
```

since my routing_key is "event.payment.*", is there any way to know exactly what event is beeing received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look and it looks like you can implement `work_with_params` as opposed to `work` and you'll be passed additional parameters.

Reference https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/blob/9de1f485648d884036347c6bea81cf4d9edaa7b9/lib/sneakers/worker.rb#L57